# Style/Template a DataGridView For Behind-Code-Use WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I have to create data grids on the fly using the code behind WPF. I have to add new DataGrids on the fly to my window, but I would like them to be formated similar. I cannot get the Style to work though. I need 2 columns: Name and Value. I plan to bind the datagrids to different data as it is created.

Any help would be appreciated. The documentation for this kind of stuff is very... scattered.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Name="Template" TargetType="DataGrid">
    <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGrid">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Title"  IsReadOnly="True">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Label></Label>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Label></Label>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

EDIT:
Not sure how else to explain it.

So say I have a stack panel on my window. On this stack panel, I would like to add DataGrids to it whenever I please. I'll be able to do MyStackPanel.Children.add(MyGrid).

Now, MyGrid could have an entirely different ItemsSource every time I add a new, unique Grid. But what I always want to stay the same between grids is the 2 columns - Title and Value.

All of my data will be something like:
Dictionary myData

The String is the title, the int is the value.
 I would like to have every grid that I add to have a unique "myData" applied to them. I can do this no problem if I setup 3 distinct grids on startup. But the issue lies in creating multiple grids on the fly. 
Maybe the client wants 50 different DataGrids on 1 stack panel. I just want to ensure the formatting is the same for every grid with Title and Value without having to creating a static amount of grids in XAML for when the program launches.

So I can go:

```
DataGrid MyGrid = new DataGrid();
MyGrid.Style = MyXAMLStyle;
MyGrid.ItemsSource = MyData;
MyStackPanel.Children.Add(MyGrid);
```

instead of doing something nasty like copying, which may be simple with 2 columns but increasingly becomes crazy. And this doesn't even work as is anyway:

```
     DataGrid template = new DataGrid();
     DataGridColumn c = CustomStats.Columns[0];
     template.Columns.Add(c);
     c = CustomStats.Columns[1];
     template.Columns.Add(c);
     template.ItemsSource = MyData;
     MyStackPanel.Children.Add(template);
```

Comment: With all due respect, your *documentation for this kind of stuff is very... scattered* comment is... ridiculous to say the least. Do you know how many good results you get from searching for *WPF DataGrid tutorial*? If you really mean that, you *clearly* haven't looked very hard. Furthermore, you'll need to provide *all* of the relevant details for your problem, which you haven't so far. Please show the data bound class(es) at least.

Comment: The issue with WPF DataGrid tutorial search is that the results have absolutely nothing to with what I'm trying to achieve. Whats ridiculous is that it feels like you haven't looked yourself. The results are about defining and styling ONE PREDEFINED grid on start. Not being able to instantiate multiple grids on the fly using either an already existing grid or one with a style. And ontop of that, any kind of search for WPF DataGrid styles results in WPF Datagrid that only have specific rows with specific data bindings. As opposed to column definitions, which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: The data bound classes are irrelevant in this case. I'm looking for any kind of rescource or explanation about styling a grid template in XAML or C# which I can use to create multiple grids with said template using C# in the code-behind. With or without the data binding. The column templates are more of whats important. Just short of creating some nasty "grid copy" function that requires a bunch of copying of formatting that seems pretty unnatural and goes against the ease-of-use Styling/Templating is supposed to solve, I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching and digging, for the proper syntax I decided to go with a pre-defined datagrid and then using a Control Item. Which was nothing how I originally wanted but I managed to tweak it to work.

It turned out that you cannot style column headers on their own using the Setter property. You have to define the grid itself and use ControlItem with the style set to your datagrid.

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataGrid x:Key="CustomGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Shared="False" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Title"  IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=title}"></Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Content="{Binding Path=value}"></Label>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="GridBase">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="Panel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">

    </StackPanel>

  </Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
  ContentControl t = new ContentControl();
  t.Content = window.Resources["CustomGrid"];
  t.DataContext = MyData;
  window.Panel.Children.Add(t);
```